# Hiding Navigation bar in JASidePanels and display custom navigation bar

Tags: uinavigationcontroller

How to hide the navigation bar of the center panel in JASidePanel and show custom bar and also have a custom button and then show the left panel of the controller??

The link is

https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels

and also how to manage memory for the center panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try reading the header file JASidePanelController.h as it explains most of your questions.

To hide the navigation bar, on the centre panel do something like:

```
[sidePanelController.centerPanel.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

To customise the bar, try:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

To show the custom button, subclass JASidePanelController and override:

```
+ (UIImage *)defaultImage;
```

Finally, to show the left panel, try:

```
[sidePanelController showLeftPanelAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: instead of leftbarbuttonitem can i have a button and link it to the leftviewcontroller? can you tel me how to link that??